# graphic problem after updating Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: updates, graphics, nvidia-optimus

I had a very stable and functional Ubuntu 13.04 until yesterday that I accepted to update the system. After the update files were downloaded, the updater told me that some packages are not needed any more and asked if it should remove them. I answered Yes, and the updater deleted the old packages.
After a restart I faced [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XmxkC.jpg) strange problem. My desktop is dead, there is no wallpaper, and every notification stays on the desktop.

Any suggestions? I have no idea what the updates were about or what packages I deleted. I have a Lenovo [W520](http://www.lenovo.com/shop/americas/content/pdf/system_data/w520_tech_specs.pdf) machine. With Nvidia,Quadro 1000M, optimus driver installed. I had installed the bumblebee package.

I just noticed that the Ubuntu Software Center crashes after a few seconds.

Comment: Please can you let us know what graphics card you are using and what system (PC, Mac, Laptop)?

Answer (score 0):

I got this exact same problem when I had been tinkering with the CompizConfig Settings Manager. I got the computer looking prity, then I changed the screen resolution of my NVIDIA graphics drivers...

## Solution

I unticked the Motion blur settings in the CompizConfig Settings Manager. Everything settled down.

Comment: I do not have CompizConfig Manager installed. Should I install it?

Comment: Not necessary. If it's not installed, this isn't the answer.